# SoundCloud API - Playback Count is smaller than actual count

Tags: python, api, soundcloud

I am using soundcloud api through python SDK.

When I get the tracks data through 'Search',
the track attribute 'playback_count' seems to be
smaller than the actual count seen on the web.

How can I avoid this problem and get the actual playback_count??

(ex.
this track's playback_count gives me 2700,
but its actually 15k when displayed on the web
https://soundcloud.com/drumandbassarena/ltj-bukem-soundcrash-mix-march-2016
)

note: this problem does not occur for comments or likes.

following is my code

```
##Search##
tracks = client.get('/tracks', q=querytext, created_at={'from':startdate},duration={'from':startdur},limit=200)

outputlist = []
trackinfo = {}
resultnum = 0

for t in tracks:
    trackinfo = {}
    resultnum += 1

    trackinfo["id"] = resultnum
    trackinfo["title"] =t.title
    trackinfo["username"]= t.user["username"]
    trackinfo["created_at"]= t.created_at[:-5]
    trackinfo["genre"] = t.genre
    trackinfo["plays"] = t.playback_count
    trackinfo["comments"] = t.comment_count
    trackinfo["likes"] =t.likes_count
    trackinfo["url"] = t.permalink_url

    outputlist.append(trackinfo)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Playback count is much lower than on SC page or the SC Pulse App. After some counts it seems to get stucked. And it is on every user, not only on mine. It occured about 2 weeks or so... Hopefully some SoundCloud Engineers will read this and fix this soon.

Comment: Same problem here, FWIW.

Comment: I have noticed this as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with the playback count being incorrect when reported via the API.

I have encountered this when getting data via the /me endpoint for activity and likes to mention a couple.

*The first image shows the information returned when accessing the sound returned for the currently playing track in the soundcloud widget*

[image: Information when accessing via the "Sound" returned for the currently playing track in the soundcloud widget]

*Information returned via the api for the me/activities endpoint*

[image: information for the same track via the /me/activities endpoint of the API for]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the SoundCloud website, they actually call a second version of the API to populate the track list on the user page.  It's similar to the documented version, but not quite the same.

If you issue a request to https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/stream/users/[userid]?limit=20&client_id=[clientid] then you'll get back a JSON object showing the same numbers you see on the web.

Since this is an undocumented version, I'm sure it'll change the next time they update their website.